# A problem caused by mathabx package

Tags: mathabx

I am sorry, but I don't usually know the meaning of LaTeX codes, I just copy them. I want to use this command:

```
\newcommand{\acts}{\mathrel{\reflectbox{$\righttoleftarrow$}}}
```

And, to use this command, I wrote

```
\usepackage{mathabx}

\usepackage{epsfig}
```

above.

Also, in my cover page I have the codes (given by the university)

```
\title{THESIS TITLE}

\degree{B.S, My Department, My University, 2013}
```

When I run it, I get the error

> **!Latex Error: Command '\degree' already defined. See the latex manual ...**

Also, when I say "go to error" it goes to the last line of my first definition, that is

```
\begin{defn}{\label{somedefinition}}

Here is the first line of the definition

The second line of the definition **(the error sends me here)**

\end{defn}
```

Any solution to this problem is fine, and I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: The package `mathabx` defines a command `\degree` which producethe symbol for Celsius degree, for example. So since you are using the command `\degree{}` again (to define the BS) you got an error.

Comment: do not load `epsfig` load `graphicx` (not related to the `\degree` error)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replace

```
\usepackage{mathabx}

\usepackage{epsfig}
```

by

```
\let\savedegree\degree
\let\degree\relax
\usepackage{mathabx}
\let\degree\savedegree

\usepackage{graphicx}
```

The `\let` just temporarily undefine `\degree` and so the package does not complain, then puts the thesis class definition back.

The `epsfig` package should not be used, so that's an unrelated change.